# How to convert a Uni<Response> object into a String?

Tags: java, java-stream, quarkus, tostring, mutiny

I am using a Quarkus application which have a dependent client service which pass me the response as a Uni object type

```
Uni<Response> response = clinetService.someMethod(id);
```

Now I need to pass this response to a another client cache service as a String:

```
cacheService(id, mapObj, responseObjectAsAString);
```

So I need to pass this converted String value to the above method.

I tried multiple ways to serialize/convert it into a String using `ObjectMapper writeValueAsString(obj)` method or Gson class `.toJson(obj)`, but nothing worked.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: What is `Response`? And what is `clinetService`?

Comment: Response is a class of jakarta.ws.rs.core library.
clientService is an object of a class provided by a client service, output of which is an object of type Uni<Response>.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to solve two tasks:

1. Convert the `Uni<Response>` into a `Uni<String>`
2. Convert the `Uni<String>` into a `String`

The first can probably be as easy as this:

```
Uni<String> body = response.map(r -> r.readEntity(String.class));
```

The second can be done using `UniAwait`. A full example:

```
String body = response.map(r -> r.readEntity(String.class))
        .await()
        .indefinitely();
```

You can also use `atMost` instead of `indefinitely`, and you can put `asOptional()` between `await()` and `indefinitely()` to return an `Optional<String>` instead.